# Running Queries within sp_send_dbmail command - Formatting issue? Need to declare the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail

This is the Query I'm trying to run:

```
Select COUNT(dbo.SO_Header.Sales_Order) AS NumberOfSalesOrders
from dbo.SO_Header
where dbo.SO_Header.Order_Taken_By is NULL
and dbo.SO_Header.Status = 'Open'
```

When I run it, it gives me the correct result. However, when I try to use it within sp_send_dbmail, I get an error. Here's my query:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Default Profile', 
 @recipients = 'example@email.com',
 @subject = 'SQLBot Message #JBUpdate',
 @query = 'SELECT COUNT(SO_Header.Sales_Order) AS NumberOfSalesOrders
          from SO_Header
          where SO_Header.Order_Taken_By is NULL
          and SO_Header.Status = 'Open'',
 @body =  'Here is the number of Open Sales Orders with no Order Taken By',
```

This is the error I get:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

Do I need to define the database to select SO_Header from? (It's different than msdb). Although, I thought that Queries ran separately from the sp_send_dbmail command. I'm fairly new to SQL, so please bear with me if this is a very simple issue to resolve.

I'm looking to have the results:

```
NumberOfSalesOrders
344
```

embedded into the body of the email I'm trying to send.

Big picture here, I'm attempting to email this to a Slack Channel via IFTTT, to provide a variety of daily updates. That step I've been able to test and make work, which is pretty slick. Now I just need to make some actual results show up...

Thanks for the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another forum.
Two solutions...

1. If this is going to be a regular email then create a view and just select from the View for the email.
2. Set your query as a string like this

'SELECT COUNT(SO_Header.Sales_Order) AS NumberOfSalesOrders from SO_Header where SO_Header.Order_Taken_By is NULL and SO_Header.Status = ' + '''' + 'Open' + ''''

Also...

If dbo.SO_Header is not in msdb (and it shouldn't be); amend your script to exclude the USE msdb bit and qualify sp_spend_dbmail as EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_spend_dbmail.